# Salesforce IP ranges available in easily parsable format?

Tags: ip-whitelisting

Salesforce publishes their IP ranges at https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000321501&type=1.
Our IT adds these IP ranges to an allowlist and has to keep the allowlist up-to-date. They would like to fully automate this by regularly scraping the page and automatically updating their allowlist.

Apart from this help article, is there another place where Salesforce publishes their IP ranges in a format that is easier to parse or less likely to change, like a text only version, or as JSON, like [AWS does](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html)?

Comment: I wonder if the ASNs (Autonomous System Number, used in BGP routing) would be helpful here. AS14340 and AS32870 are Salesforce's, but those don't seem to cover everything Salesforce lists on the help article (and I don't have access to a CLI with whois to see what ASNs the other ranges are part of).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't what you're directly asking for, but can make life a little easier in this regard. There is a `General Message` posted on the trust site around 2 weeks before trusted IP range changes are made. Below is a screenshot of the last update/general message from May 2021. Generally, messages are posted the first week of the month and the changes go into effect around the 15th of the month.

[image]

The trust site does have a way to easily digest these messages through the [Status API](https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/docs/) (*only provides recent messages*).

`https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/generalMessages?limit=1000&offset=0`

```
[
    {
        "id":414,
        "subject":"Coronavirus (COVID-19) Update",
        "body":"As we continue to evaluate business...",
        "startDate":"2020-03-17T18:53:46.949Z",
        "endDate":null,
        "externalId":null,
        "createdAt":"2020-03-17T18:55:00.400Z",
        "updatedAt":"2021-09-21T18:00:51.294Z"
    },
    ...
]
```

It's not the ideal automation setup, but does allow your IT team to automate a way to notify them when they need to check the docs and plan to add changes to the IP Addresses versus it potentially not happening.